# How to put a static name for files generated in the bundle?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bundle, vue-cli

I'm working on an MPA application with Vue CLI, and the moment I make the bundle, Webpack generates the files automatically. The output file list is something like this:

```
chunk-vendors.7f809fbd.js
chunk-common.aae8cb13.js
home.f85a21ab.js
chunk-common.9113b70b.css
etc...
```

Is it possible to manually define the name of these generated files? I want filenames like this:

```
chunk-vendors.my-standard.js
chunk-common.my-standard.js
home.my-standard.js
chunk-common.my-standard.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the following Vue CLI config (from [`vuejs/vue-cli#1967`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1967#issuecomment-408606835)):

```js
// vue.config.js
const chunkPrefix = '[name].my-standard'

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
      .use('url-loader')
      .tap(options => Object.assign({}, options, { name: `${chunkPrefix}.[ext]` }));
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: `${chunkPrefix}.css`,
      chunkFilename: `${chunkPrefix}.css`,
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: `${chunkPrefix}.js`,
      chunkFilename: `${chunkPrefix}.js`,
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is many reasons why not to do it, and this is the reason that it is not the default behavior.

anyway, if you still want to do it, then you can use the [`filename`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#filename) property.

you can fine tweak it as you can see in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro! could you tell me what the reasons are? or give me an article that explain? I don't have much experience with bundlers and I wanted to understand better :)